# Do gamification questions go here?

Tags: discussion

I am looking into how to "gamify" aspects of our websites and services. I'm reading *Reality Is Broken* and *Gamification by Design,* to give you an idea of the sort of inquiry I'm making. I see there is https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/, but it looks to be devoted to just the nuts and bolts of development.

As I have questions for the community on gamification and user experience, how can I ask them in a way that contributes to this site and doesn't veer into other domains?

Comment: Yep, gamification goes here. I wouldn't worry about veering into other domains unless you're specifically asking about game development issues. Even game related UX issues are on topic here IMO, depending on phrasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ask them here. We already have a number of them filed under [gamification](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamification); see the [most asked questions](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamification?sort=faq&pagesize=15).